# When building fieldmappings, how do I handle the SHAPE field?

Tags: python, arcpy, field-mapping

I have a collection of hundreds of shape files and a python dictionary mapping the input field to the output field. I'm building my fieldmappings dynamically using this dictionary since it already exists and is in a configuration file, editable by the user if fields change.

How should I handle the SHAPE field? I want the geometry copied over during any merge operations. The mapping in my config file, `"SHAPE@": "SHAPE@"` (input field : output field) throws an error for the shape field but all other mappings work.

Update 3: Code included...

```
field_names = GetFieldNamesInFeatureClass(file)

fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

for input_name in field_names:

    output_name = fmFromCfg[input_name]

    fieldmap = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fieldmap.addInputField(file, input_name)

    fld = fieldmap.outputField
    fld.type = "DOUBLE"
    fld.name = output_name
    fld.aliasname = "Output Field Alias"
    fld.isNullable = True

    fieldmap.outputField = fld
    fieldmappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap)
```

The configuration file is JSON. It is read into `fmFromCfg`. Here is a simplified version with relevant section:

```
{
  "FieldMapping": {
    "FID": "OWNER",
    "SHAPE": "SHAPE"
  }
}
```

Update 2: Changed the field mapping to `"SHAPE": "SHAPE"` but I'm still getting an error, `RuntimeError: FieldMap: Error in adding input field to field map`.

Update 1: When I change the mapping to `"SHAPE": "SHAPE@"`, a match is made but I get `RuntimeError: FieldMap: Error in adding input field to field map` because the `@` at the end of the output field.

Comment: Field name probably isn't named SHAPE@. SHAPE@ has special meeting in several arcpy.da functions, but doesn't apply elsewhere.

Comment: My first comment is applicable to both input and output fields.

Comment: Changing the mapping to `"SHAPE": "SHAPE"` still results in an error, `RuntimeError: FieldMap: Error in adding input field to field map`

Comment: You might need to show your code. Not clear how you're using your config file or setting up the fieldmappings.

Comment: In the arcpy.Describe section, there is a shapeFieldName property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to express the geometry field ('SHAPE') in the fieldmappings. It will come along for the ride. (If you try to do something equivalent using a tool dialog that uses a fieldmappings, you'll notice the geometry field isn't added to the control.)

So, given that this field is in your config file, just add an `if` to exclude it.

```
for input_name in field_names:

    output_name = fmFromCfg[input_name]

    if output_name != 'SHAPE':
        fieldmap = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fieldmap.addInputField(file, input_name)

        fld = fieldmap.outputField
        fld.type = "DOUBLE"
        fld.name = output_name
        fld.aliasname = "Output Field Alias"
        fld.isNullable = True

        fieldmap.outputField = fld
        fieldmappings.addFieldMap(fieldmap)
```

**Update:**

Or better yet, filter out the geometry field when you create your list of field names. I can't see into your `GetFieldNamesInFeatureClass` function, but something equivalent to:

```
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(file) if f.type != 'Geometry']
```

Comment: It would be more generically applicable to data sources where the geometry column is not always "SHAPE" if you get the type of the field and test on geometry type.

Comment: Agreed. Best spot to do that might be in @DenaliHardtail's `GetFieldNamesInFeatureClass` function.

Comment: Just as a catch all, it may be best to filter all non-required fields: `fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if not f.required]`.  This will also exclude fields like OBJECTID.